# Zend framework mysql php custom install

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm installing a custom Zend installation and I am getting this error when I go to the index.php in my browser.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] 
Access denied for user 'sitename'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in
 /home3/sitename/public_html/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129 Stack trace: #0 
/home3/sitename/public_html/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): PDO-
>__construct('mysql:host=loca...', '', '', Array) #1


/home3/sitename/public_html/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() 

#2 /home3/sitename/public_html/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(448): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() 

#3 /home3/sitename/public_html/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array) 

#4 /home3/sitename/application/bootstrap.php(65): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8') 

#5 /home3/sitename/public_html/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(665): Bootstrap->_initDB() 

#6 /home3/sitename/public_html/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(618): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract- in /home3/sitename/public_html/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144
```

Any help would be appreciated. I believe I have the directory structure right but any help in the right direction will do.

Comment: ru using mysql or sql.if ur using mysql change the connection pdo to mysql .check this url once http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html

Comment: your host, username, password or database name is wrong

Comment: I can't seem to find the file where I add the details of my newly created database?

Comment: I can't seem to point at the database. I'm getting

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in /home3/sitename/public_html/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129`

Answer (score 0):

check your application.ini, at /application/configs

```
resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "database"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```